# How to constraint UITableView over UIView in UIView subclass and keep dataSource and delegate methods in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to constraint UITableView over UIView in UIView subclass and keep dataSource and delegate methods in UIViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a var inside the custom view like

```
weak var delegate:VCName?
```

Then inside it add the table and set

```
self.tableView.delegate = delegate
self.tableView.dataSource = delegate
```

---

```
class CustomView:UIView {

    weak var delegate:VCName?
    init(frame: CGRect,del:VCName) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        delegate = del
        setup()
    }
    func setup() {
      // add table here with constraints 
      self.tableView.delegate = delegate
      self.tableView.dataSource = delegate
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: I previously initialized my CustomView in viewController's loadView(), like this "view = MyView()". What should I pass now as a frame argument?

Comment: You can pass `UIScreen.main.bounds`

Answer (score 0):

Make the constraints inside myView and set the delegate and datasource in VC like:

```
myView.myTableView.delegate = self
myView.myTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: shouldn't this be encapsulated inside the custom view? is that access level should be ok ? won't it cause a repeatable code if the op used  that view in many places

Comment: This should work well. Just make sure your VC is UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: To answer about repetitive code: if user wants to define what's in myTableView in myView, and myView has no effect on rest of the views in VC then it would be better to keep the data source and delegate in myView, of course. Otherwise, delegate in VC is fine.